# sequential import or simultaneous import in Oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, import, sequential

I've to import two different databases dump to a same oracle server like
abc.dmp import to abc user
xyz.dmp import to xyz user

What is the advisable way for doing this - import sequentially, first import one and then on completion import second or import both dumps simultaneously.

Suggestions much appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: There is no right or wrong way to do this, it varies according to your particular circumstance. For instance, how many unused CPUs do you have? No point in running in parallel if there's only one CPU to do the job. Are there dependencies (foreign keys, code execution privileges) across the schemas? Then you need to deploy in dependency order. What's the rollback requirement if one schema fails? If you need to import the whole shebang or nothing it might make sense to install only one at a time. Unless you have a time constraint and the windows not large enough to import them all serially ….

Comment: Thanks for prompt response APC ! they both are independent databases with no relation, the machine has two CPUs. yes, the time window is not large enough that's why Am looking for comparison between parallel and serial approach

Comment: Then there is no question here. You have to run both imports simultaneously.